# Can dplyr and data.table be used traditionally and inside loops to extract results from data frames?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame of over 700,000 observations and four variables and would like to extract some values by first indexing one of the District variables (shown here as `Dist`):

```
Date         X      Y    Dist
2003/01    2.4    5.5       1
2003/02    2.3    4.0       1
2003/03    1.9    4.4       1
      .
      .
      .
2004/11    3.7    2.9     700
2004/12    2.6    5.9     700
```

That is, a dataset of Xs and Ys for 700 districts, with each district having an yearly record for Xs and Ys. For each district, some values need to be extracted so I thought I could use dplyr here instead of traditional loops and conditions; however, I'm new to it and not very used to its syntax and inspite of passing some efficient commands, I'm not getting the proper results. The resulting data frame should look something like:

```
X           Dist
Some avg.      5
```

Or even values for multiple districts, arranged in ascending order:

```
X           Dist
Some avg.      4
       "       5
       "       6
```

At first, I 'sliced' off data for the districts and saved it as `test` to extract mean and number of non-NA observations but the resulting dataset contained warnings that I'm unclear why. For example, for districts 1 to 10:

`test <- slice(df, Dist == c(1:10))`

Gave a warning of longer object length being not a multiple of shorter object. I could slice for each district, and merge them row-wise but that is tedious. I actually used a for loop to come up with similar values but those are simply incomparable when it comes to dplyr's efficiency and speed in extracting valuable insights through just one-liners instead of lines of codes and conditions. It simply speeds up everything besides making markdown files cleaner and readable. How can the chained operation `%>%` be used here to come up with similar results? Can they be used with traditional loops and conditions?

Comment: Just do `df %>% group_by(Dist) %>% summarise(X = mean(X))` in `dplyr` or `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, .(X = mean(X)), by = Dist]`

Comment: `slice(df, Dist == c(1:10))` is wrong. You can either use `slice(df, 1:10)` to get the first 10 rows of your datat or `filter(df, Dist %in% 1:10)` to get all rows where Dist is between 1 and 10 (integer)

Comment: Thanks! Can `df %>% group_by(Dist == c(1:10))` be used for specific districts?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for the heads up! I'll see if that works.

Comment: Use `filter` first i.e. `df %>% filter(Dist %in% 1:10) %>% group_by(Dist) %>% summarise(X= mean(X))`